# Linebreaks disappear from xsl

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, line-breaks

I got a, probably small, problem. 
ATM I'm creating an XSL file as a template for a pdf and it was all looking good and stuff. 
But then I must have changed something and suddenly all the linebreaks in the output stopped working.
Loading text from XML that contains linebreaks works, but even making a linebreak in the XSL doesnt work, also & #xA; doesnt work anymore.

I guess I kinda broke something and someone probably already realized how I screwed up.
So some help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** this answer is based on the premise that you are using XSLT to create an XSL-FO file, processed to create a PDF (this is not perfectly clear from your question).

The description *"the linebreaks stopped working"* can be interpreted as different problems:

1. `fo:block`s create a single, long line which overflows the margins and possibly ends beyond the page limits

**Possible cause:** have you added some `keep-together` properties? Setting `keep-together="always"` in a block-level formatting objects is equivalent to setting `keep-together.within-page="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-line="always"` and forces the formatter to build a single line containing all the text of the block.

**Suggested solution:** if you want to avoid a *page* break splitting your block, use `keep-together.within-page="always"`

2. line breaks present in the XSL-FO file are ignored in the PDF

**Possible cause:** have you removed or modified some `linefeed-treatment` properties? Line breaks in the input XSL-FO, both manual line breaks and `&#x000A;` entities, are usually treated as normal spaces and collapsed with other adjacent spaces.

So, even if your input file has:

```
<fo:block>This
is a block
with
line breaks.
</fo:block>
```

the result is just:

```
This is a block with line breaks.
```

**Suggested solution:** use the property `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` in the `fo:block` elements containg the line breaks you want to maintain.